# fill down with a condition on the dynamic column names (powerquery)

Tags: excel, powerquery

Here is my code so far

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"Id No", Int64.Type}, {"Name", type text}, {"Surname", type text}, {"Date", type datetime}, {"Hour(s)", type number}, {"Activity Code", type text}, {"Activity", type text}, {"Crew", type text}, {"Duty", type text}, {"Subcontractor", type text}, {"Account Group (Description)", type text}, {"Status", type text}, {"Cost Code", type any}, {"Group", type any}}),
    #"Filtered Rows" = Table.SelectRows(#"Changed Type", each [Status] <> "ABSENCE WITHOUT PERMISSION"),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Filtered Rows",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Removed Columns" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Changed Type1",{"Status", "Cost Code", "Group", "Activity Code", "Activity", "Subcontractor", "Account Group (Description)"}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Removed Columns",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Id No", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US")[Date]), "Date", "Hour(s)", List.Sum)
in
    #"Pivoted Column"
```

i have column names dynamically changing for each month.

what i am trying to do is "to fill down the null rows under the dates which are not Sunday with `AB`

I can manually add a column for each not sunday manually to do it but next month the dates and so the names and sundays will change.

the sample file is [here](https://drive.google.com/open?id=1wZQPgqKkrxnbe-fhaIYnhaAu3waaQTA_)

*** while writing i had an idea to insert "AB" before pivoting it, i will try...

***EDIT***

After this idea, here is my new code :

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Id No", "Name", "Surname", "Crew", "Duty", "Date", "Status"}, {{"Sum Hours", each List.Sum([#"Hour(s)"]), type number}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each if [Status] = "ABSENCE WITHOUT PERMISSION" then "AB" else [Sum Hours]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Conditional Column",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Custom", "Hour(s)"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Sum Hours", "Status"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type1",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Id No", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US")[Date]), "Date", "Hour(s)", List.Sum),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Pivoted Column", {{"11/1/2019", "AB"}, {"11/2/2019", "AB"}, {"11/3/2019", "AB"}, {"11/4/2019", "AB"}, {"11/5/2019", "AB"}, {"11/6/2019", "AB"}, {"11/7/2019", "AB"}, {"11/8/2019", "AB"}, {"11/9/2019", "AB"}, {"11/10/2019", "AB"}, {"11/11/2019", "AB"}, {"11/12/2019", "AB"}, {"11/13/2019", "AB"}, {"11/14/2019", "AB"}, {"11/15/2019", "AB"}, {"11/16/2019", "AB"}, {"11/17/2019", "AB"}, {"11/18/2019", "AB"}, {"11/19/2019", "AB"}, {"11/20/2019", "AB"}, {"11/21/2019", "AB"}, {"11/22/2019", "AB"}, {"11/23/2019", "AB"}, {"11/24/2019", "AB"}, {"11/25/2019", "AB"}, {"11/26/2019", "AB"}, {"11/27/2019", "AB"}, {"11/28/2019", "AB"}, {"11/29/2019", "AB"}, {"11/30/2019", "AB"}})
in
    #"Replaced Errors"
```

but I get `error` because of "AB" and therefore i have to replace the errors, and the last part of the code comes with static dates on the `Table.ReplaceErrorValues`

Is there any syntax to write `allcolumns` instead of the column names one by one ? something like this :

```
#"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Pivoted Column", {ALLCOLUMNS, "AB"})
```

**FINAL CODE** DONE !

```
    let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Id No", "Name", "Surname", "Crew", "Duty", "Date", "Status"}, {{"Sum Hours", each List.Sum([#"Hour(s)"]), type number}}),
    #"Added Conditional Column" = Table.AddColumn(#"Grouped Rows", "Custom", each if [Status] = "ABSENCE WITHOUT PERMISSION" and Date.DayOfWeekName([Date],"en-US") <> "Sunday" then "AB" else [Sum Hours]),
    #"Changed Type" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Added Conditional Column",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Renamed Columns" = Table.RenameColumns(#"Changed Type",{{"Custom", "Hour(s)"}}),
    #"Removed Columns1" = Table.RemoveColumns(#"Renamed Columns",{"Sum Hours", "Status"}),
    #"Changed Type1" = Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Removed Columns1",{{"Date", type date}}),
    #"Sorted Rows" = Table.Sort(#"Changed Type1",{{"Date", Order.Ascending}, {"Id No", Order.Ascending}}),
    #"Pivoted Column" = Table.Pivot(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US"), List.Distinct(Table.TransformColumnTypes(#"Sorted Rows", {{"Date", type text}}, "en-US")[Date]), "Date", "Hour(s)", List.Sum),
    #"Replaced Errors" = Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Pivoted Column", 
                      List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"), each {_, "AB"}))
in
    #"Replaced Errors"
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
is there any syntax to write "allcolumns" instead of the column names one by one ?
```

Yes, sure, you may use **Table.ColumnNames** function. For your example:

```
= Table.ReplaceErrorValues(#"Pivoted Column", 
                      List.Transform(Table.ColumnNames(#"Pivoted Column"), each {_, "AB"}))
```

Comment: 'spasibo bolshoy bratan... '